# ios , macos and xcode version compatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, macos

I have a React-native project that works fine in the simulator but I am not able run that project on my physical device.
My version is like

- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Xcode 14
- ios 17 on my iPhone

so with this type of version compatibility, I am able to run my app on a physical device ??